# Database corruption on VM shutdown

Tags: sql-server, azure, corruption, azure-vm

We moved a SQL Server database to a virtual machine in Azure.

Since the database only contains historical data and does not have transactions anymore we want to turn off and turn on the VM on a schedule to reduce costs.

As far as I know database corruption can happen if the machine restarts in the middle of a transaction, so I have three questions about this:

1. Can database corruption happen in a database that does not have transaction anymore when the machine is shut down?
2. Is there a correct way to shut down the machine and avoid a corruption scenario?
3. Should we leave this machine running 7 x 24?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> As far as I know database corruption can happen if the machine restart in the middle of a transaction

No.  Database corruption is only caused by faults in the storage system or bugs.  SQL Server will perform crash recovery on startup to recover any databases that have un-applied transaction log records, or have been altered by transactions that did not commit.

This is a procedure that is *very* well tested and runs on thousands of production databases every day.

Having a normal SQL Server backup is sufficient protection in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of situations where you can get inte trouble if you kill the machine:

If the disk subsystem don't live ut to some rules (like write ordering). There's a tool named SQLIOSIM.EXE installed with SQL Server that you can use to test these things. Considering you are on Azure, I'd be surprised if you have any issues in that area. More info in this classic whitepaper: https://bobsql.com/sql-server-i-o-basics-chapter-1/#_Toc92876356

If you shutdown in the middle of a huge transaction so you have a massive rollback taking place at startup and there's not enough space for the ldf file to grow.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Ill have a look at the tool and the paper